# How To Limit WooCommerce Shipping Extension Based on Zones Instead of Countries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a WooCommerce Shipping Extension. At the moment it works but only limits according to countries. But I need to limit according to country states (provinces), regions, cities and zones. Below is my current code that limits according to countries:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->id = 'tiki_lite';
    $this->method_title = __('Tiki Local Delivery');
    $this->method_description = __('Custom local delivery method for Tiki Lite');
    $this->availability = 'including';
    $this->countries = array(
        'ZA',
        'ES',
        'US',
        'GB'
    );
    $this->init();
    $this->enabled = isset($this->settings['enabled']) ? $this->settings['enabled'] : 'yes';
    $this->title = isset($this->settings['title']) ? $this->settings['title'] : __('Tiki Local Delivery', 'tiki_lite');
}
```

So when the above mentioned countries are not selected, Tiki Local Deliveries is not one of the shipping options. But now I want to go ahead and also add a country_state as a limiter. I have tried to do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
    $states['ZA'] = array(
        'GP' => __( 'Gauteng', 'tiki_lite' )
    );
    return $states;
}
```

This I came across as I was searching for answers, but this works for all of WooCommerce and not just my extension. I only want to remove my extension from being an option when other a specific state, zone, province or region is selected on the shipping address.

I then tried this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->id = 'tiki_lite';
    $this->method_title = __('Tiki Local Delivery');
    $this->method_description = __('Custom local delivery method for Tiki Lite');
    // Contreis availability
    $this->availability = 'including';
    $this->countries = array(
        'ZA',
        'ES',
        'US',
        'GB'
    );
    $this->states['ZA'] = array(
        'GP' => __( 'Gauteng', 'Tiki Lite' )
    );
    $this->init();
    $this->enabled = isset($this->settings['enabled']) ? $this->settings['enabled'] : 'yes';
    $this->title = isset($this->settings['title']) ? $this->settings['title'] : __('Tiki Local Delivery', 'tiki_lite');
}
```

This does nothing however and so I am at a complete loss right now. I have even tried the forums but either they are too congested or they don't have the answers, because I kept finding how to setup shipping zones as an admin and not as an extension dev. I have searched but currently can't find the documentation or code snippets that talks about doing this. Please help a dev.